# Is it "pose" or "poses"?

Tags: grammaticality

> Reasoning about systems pose/poses a challenge

Should it be singular or plural? And, I'd be happy to know why.

Thanks!

Comment: "poses", since the subject noun "reasoning" is singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjugation of "to pose" is the following:

> I pose
>
> You pose
>
> He/she/it poses
>
> We pose
>
> They pose

Since the subject here is the third person singular ("it"), the correct word is **poses**

Source: http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-pose.html

Comment: but our weird poses

Comment: @SPnL in that context, "pose" is a noun, so you can pluralise it. In the OP, however, it functions as a verb, meaning it has to follow its conjugation rules.

Answer (score 0):

In the word group 'reasoning about systems', reasoning is subject; hence 'Reasoning about systems poses a challenge.'